# Wordpress URL for albums in Nextgen plugin changed for no reason

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

Not really a programming question (I think) but for some reason some URL's of my Wordpress blog changed.

It has only affected pages created for the Nextgen plugin.

Basically I have a photo gallery divided up by years, then months. The URL's used to be

mydomain.com/photo-gallery/2013

now they are

mydomain.com/photo-gallery/2013-2

ALL my pages from 2007-2013 have been changed with the addition of '-2' and it is causing errors to do with crawls and incoming links resulting in 404 rather than the correct photo gallery page.

I have tried to edit the permalink in the Wordpress admin section but it won't let me remove the '-2' from each page.

I am confused and not sure what to do. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WordPress questions like this are tough to answer definitively because there are thousands of hosts, thousands of plug ins and thousands of themes. So the best I can do is try to give you some trouble shooting tips. Hopefully they will point you in the right direction.

**Try these in the order listed.**

---

Try a changing the text in a different browser.

Update the plugin if necessary. There may be an update for 3.7.

Disable all plugins and try to change the URL.

Check your .htaccess file in the root folder of your site.

Set Debug = true in wp-config and see if any errors come up when the page loads.

The reason that you might be unable to edit the file is because you don't have write permissions. However, you do have read permissions so you can see it. If you're using FileZilla you can right click on the folder and view the permissions for your plugin folder... *(wp-content/plugins)* I'm not sure how your server is configured but don't set the permissions of the folder to 777. They should probably be 755.

You may have malware on your site. Scan your WP site with **http://sucuri.net/**.